# Cannot type ampersand (&) character into java editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Haven't found anything useful about this on the internet. I'm using my Windows 7 installation with Hungarian keyboard layout and I cannot type in the ampersand (&) character into my Java source files using `AltGr+C` in Eclipse. I can do the same into XML files. If I change back to english keyboard layout, I can type it in using `Shift+8`.

What's blocking this shortcut in Eclipse? I can type the same into NetBeans without any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Window->Preferences then General->Keys. Search for 'Ctrl+Alt+C'.

Comment: Thanks! CheckStyle plugin was using this keyboard combination. I didn't know Ctrl+Alt+C is the same as AltGr+C :O